# Custom error message for when a regex is not matched

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using data annotation validation, and am trying to make a custom error message for when a field doesn't match my regular expression.  Here's my model:

```
    [DisplayName("EIN / SSN")]
    [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Please enter last 4 digits of EIN or SSN.")]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d{1,5}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter numeric characters.")] // 5 so it'll let the above message fire instead
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter last 4 digits of EIN or SSN Number.")]
    public string EIN { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Issued amount")]
    [RegularExpression("^-?\\d{1,13}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter numeric characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter exact dollar amount as it appears on your bank statement.")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal IssueAmount { get; set; }
```

Note: The validation for the EIN field works perfectly, but when I enter any alpha for the IssueAmount, I still get the built in error: "The value 'fgyjfgyj' is not valid for Issued Amount." Instead of "Please enter numeric characters." I've run my regex through a validator, and it seems to be matching when I want it to be.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**
View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EIN)<em>Last 4 only</em>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EIN, new {maxlength = 4})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EIN)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueAmount)<em>Must be exact amount</em>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IssueAmount, new { maxlength = 16 })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueAmount)
```

And should the code in my controller affect the errors?

Comment: Post your view and controller

Comment: This looks like the order that the validations are running needs to be changed.

Comment: What should it be changed to?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be missing an @ symbol before the regular expression. i.e.

[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,5}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter numeric characters.")]